# mysql FIND_IN_SET vs REGEXP performance

Tags: mysql, regex

I am writing a question because I have a question while using mysql.

I know it's structurally wrong.
However, it is difficult to change because a lot of data and code have already been written.

I put multiple data in one column using typeorm set.

'A,B,C,D' , 'A', 'C,D'

The data is entered as above, duplicate values ​​cannot be entered.

What is curious is that the speed is the same when using REGEXP, FIND_IN_SET because there is not enough data yet to make a difference in speed.

So I'm curious.
Of the two queries below, which one has the upper hand if I have to use it?

```
#1
SELECT *
FROM CAT
WHERE CONCAT(",", CATDATA, ",") REGEXP ",(A|B|C|D),"
```

```
#2
SELECT *
FROM CAT
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('A',CATDATA)
OR FIND_IN_SET('B',CATDATA)
OR FIND_IN_SET('C',CATDATA)
OR FIND_IN_SET('D',CATDATA)
```

Ultimately, it can be split into a different table,
but please understand that this is a query that needs to be used right now.

I wonder which one is a bit faster, #1 or #2.
thank you.

Comment: *I wonder which one is a bit faster, #1 or #2.* Only practical tests may answer. In most cases FIND_IN_SET() is more fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either formulation must check every row in the table; no `INDEX` is helpful.  The primary cost is fetching the rows.  The expression evaluation is secondary.  I don't know which is faster, but I would expect the difference (for the whole query) to be under 10%, hence not worth worrying about.

What are typeorm's limitations?  Is "A" really a single letter?  Or can it be a longer string, such as "ACE"?

Have you considered

```
SET('A','B','C','D','E','F')
```

The internal representation is 1 bit per item in the SET, and the names can be arbitrary strings (except for disallowing commas).

`SET` and `TINYINT` (being treated as up to 8 bits) will not be any faster, but will take less space.

Comment: A,B,C,D is just A,B,C,D! There are no additional words.